# Multiplication of Lie group element and Lie algebra element over field $K$.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Suppose $G$ be a Lie group over field $K$, and $\mathfrak{g}$ be its Lie algbera (again, over $K$).

Then, my question is in which case, they **share**(I'll explain this later) the same multiplication structure.

For instance, if $G$ is a matrix group over $K$, then every thing is done, since $G$ and $\mathfrak{g}$ shares the same multiplication structure in $\mathrm{Mat}_n(K)$ for some $n$. Of course, the results are not lying on neither $G$ nor $\mathfrak{g}$. But, the subalgebra generated by $G$ and $\mathfrak{g}$.

Are there good concepts about dealing with this? As we've seen, the matrix group is one of the important example. However, are there some non-trivial examples? What are the necessary, and sufficient conditions?

More precisely,
are there some (possibly non-commutative and not-matrix) algebra $A$ over $K$ in (smooth category) and there are injective smooth $K$-algebra morphism from $K[G]$ to $A$ and injective $K$-Lie algebra morphism from $\mathfrak{g}$ to $A$, whose structures are also compatible with well-know results in smooth category, for example,
$$
[X, Y] =  \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\right|_{s=0} \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right|_{t=0} \exp(tX) \exp(s Y) \exp(-tX) \exp(-sY)
$$
in terms of $A$?

Comment: What's K(G)? ${}{}$

Comment: If you want A to be finite dimensional, then since A itself is a subalgebra of a matrix algebra you will not get very far from linear groups.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Ah, I intended to write $K$-group algebra $K[G]$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Oh, I see. Then, can we say that at least for finite-dimensional case, the subalgebra of $A \subseteq \mathrm{Mat}_n(K)$ generated by $G$ and $\mathfrak{g}$ is the most tight algebra containing both of them?

Comment: Well, you have to find a faithful representation of minimal dimension (which exists as we are supposing the group is linear)

Comment: What is "$K$-Lie group morphism from $K[G]$ to $A$"? Neither $K[G]$ nor $A$ is a Lie group. Do you mean $K$-algebra morphism?